# Qt - Creating smooth rounded corners of a widget

Tags: qt, widget

I have tried creating a smooth rounded corners of a widget using method described below:

1. Create a widget with `Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and
   `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` flag;
2. Create a `QFrame` inside of a widget;
3. Set a stylesheel to `QFrame`, for example:

> ```
> border: 1px solid red;
> border-radius: 20px;
> background-color: black;
> ```

I was able to attain the smooth rounded corners but the widget is "window" type so i am not able to position the widget according to other widgets. Can we attain the complete transparency of a widget by not making the widget as "window" type?

Answer (score 16):

Your question is quite unclear. It sounds to me like this is a widget you want to add to a layout. If you want a widget with rounded corners, just use a `QFrame` and set a style-sheet to it:

```
myFrame->setStyleSheet(".QFrame{background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;}");
```

There is no need to create a widget that contains a `QFrame`. Just use `QFrame` directly.

Comment: I have also tried using QFrame directly, I set my main widget to be the parent of this rounded QFrame. I saw my rounded QFrame inside a grey rectangle whose width and height is equal to this rounded frame. I even tried setting the transparent palette for the Base as well as Background but it was not working.

Comment: @parveenarora Could you post a picture in your question of the result you get and the result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right - then you may use [`QGraphicsOpacityEffect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) class for any "non-window" widget.